# Can't reinstall grub after coning partitions to new drive (Debian 8 / Jessie)

Tags: boot, debian, grub

I had a drive failure and restored a recent image to a replacement drive.  I can't seem to get `grub` installed on the new drive.  I can only boot using a bootable grub USB key that finds the bootable volume (with prompts), but it's annoying and doesn't work for remote reboots.

I'm getting:

```
# grub-install /dev/sda
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
The file /boot/grub/stage1 not read correctly.
```

I can't seem to find any working answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I'm embarrassed, it was as simple as `apt-get install grub2 -y`

Comment: And then `grub-install /dev/sda`? Or was sole `apt_get ...` enough?